# Making a K type thermocouple

Tags: thermocouple

It has been said that a K type thermocouple is just 2 wires of different types twisted together (basically). If this is so then can such a thermocouple be made with a copper and steel wire twisted together? What about copper and nichrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A thermocouple is made from two different conductors in contact - frequently welded, but twisting together will work too.

A type K thermocouple is made with chromel and alumel conductors.  There are many types of thermocouple, designated by different letters, and using different metals.  See the Wikipedia article on thermocouples, or do a web search for "thermocouple types" for more information.